# Irritating Google Chrome tab drag causes it to go full-screen

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen, browser-tabs

When I want to drag my tabs around to left and right, Chrome insists on pulling it out of its window. Even if Chrome is maximised, it pulls it out of the window to make its own. The only way to keep it in the window with the rest is if the entire browser window is about 50px down the screen. Is there a way to stop this behaviour, or is it actually intended behaviour?

(I do love that Chrome lets you pull tabs out to make new windows - it just seems strange that it is so difficult to keep tabs in their original windows)

Comment: I'm not getting this on the latest stable version. Dragging tabs left and right works as expected.

Comment: Me neither, but it does occur on slow systems

Comment: This is happening again to me now in 2022. Am I the only one?
Version 102.0.5005.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worked it out - it seems as though running ObjectDock is somehow causing Chrome to think that the top of the monitor is lower than it is or something along those lines: this problem isn't reproducible on my other monitor, or when I close ObjectDock

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a known issue, which will be addressed in the next release

I'll update once [I have the source](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=292771a78a1fdab2&hl=en)

> the annoying tab tearing problem is
>   already fixed in the current dev build
>
> it will drill down to the beta and
>   stable eventually, but it is finally
>   solved here is how to get the dev for
>   those who can';t wait
>
> http://dev.chromium.org/getting-involved/dev-channel

Comment: is this the same bug/issue that causes the problem I see: if you click on a different tab, and there's some delay in displaying the page (memory caching?) and you move the mouse before the page is displayed, the tab will tear out to wherever your mouse is when it does eventually catch up.

Comment: @geocoin: I don't think it's the same problem, but I hope this solution works for that one as well, it's driving me crazy!